# Why Edittext is not working in my code ?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-edittext

I am new to Android Application programming, 
In the primary level , I can't fix it, Could anyone can help me then I can go ahead to learn?

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_text"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="hello">Hello World, Example3Activity!</string>
<string name="app_name">Example3</string>
<string name="hint_text">Enter your name</string>

</resources>
```

error message:
Error parsing XML: no element found

Comment: If the XML is exactly as posted, you're missing a `<` right at the start!

Comment: where are you getting this problem>

Comment: Try cleaning the project. Often times XML errors likes these deal with eclipse and its not cleaning the R properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is your problem but you can have a look at this [post](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=31088)

Basically it is saying, if this occurred, you need to delete the main.out.xml file, (which will be regenerate), and run your application when you are in the .java file of your app instead of the xml file.

I don't know whether it will work, but give it a try.